# ColdFusion two buttons in form. One for submitting the other to run other code

Tags: forms, if-statement, coldfusion, form-submit

**Question:** Is it possible to take the information from one field in a form and save it in a static list when a button/link is clicked without submitting the form or changing the data in any of the other inputs. Could I use AJAX for something like this?

Background: I want the users to be able to add multiple phone numbers. So they can enter the number in an input click "Add Number" and that input would be empty and the number that was there is now static in an html `<li>`. When the user clicks the submit button all of those numbers in the static list will be passed with the rest of the data.

The thing I am having the most problem with is when the user clicks "Add Number" the whole form is submitted to the action page.

**What is happening:** Both buttons submit the form to the action.cfm page.

My code example:

```
    //Code in header that should run if the first button is clicked
    <cfif StructKeyExists(form,"add_number">
  This is where I would take the phone number and have it put it into a html list
    </cfif>


    <cfform action="action.cfm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <cfinput type="text" name="phone_number">

    <cfinput type="button" value="Add Number" name="add_number"/>

    //The button below should not run the logic in the header and only send the user to action.cfm
    <cfinput type="submit" value="Submit Current Order" name="submit"/>


    </cfform>
```

Comment: You have a bad plan.  Multiple submit buttons may not give the desired result if the user uses his keyboard to submit the form.  Radio buttons or a select are a better way to make the user choose something.

Comment: I updated my question and gave more background information on what I am trying to accomplish. You will see that radio buttons would not work for my case.

Comment: Adding form fields on the fly best done with javascript.

Comment: *when the user clicks "Add Number" the whole form is submitted to the action page.* A plain "button" would not submit the form. Either you are not showing us the real code, or perhaps there is some javascript attached to the button click that we cannot see.

Comment: Why are you using `<cfform>` etc, instead of just a normal HTML form & components? There is nothing in your code shown that necessitates using `<cfform>`, and it's almost always a bad approach to solving any issue one might perceive `<cfform>` might help with.

Comment: @DanBracuk not all buttons are *submit* buttons. Only `<input type="submit">` controls behave the way you describe. And for what the user wants to achieve, how would you envisage a radio or a select being part of the solution?

Comment: The comment about radio buttons was based on the original version of the question.